# Removing white spaces from files but not from directories throws an error

Tags: bash, ubuntu

I'm trying to recursively rename some files with parent folders that contain spaces, I've tried the following command in ubuntu terminal:

```
find . -type f -name '* *' -print0 | xargs -0 rename 's/ //'
```

It has given out the following error refering to the folder names:

```
Can't rename ./FOLDER WITH SPACES/FOLDER1.1/SUBFOLDER1.1/FILE.01 A.jpg
./FOLDERWITH SPACES/FOLDER1.1/SUBFOLDER1.1/FILE.01 A.jpg: No such file
or directory
```

If i'm not mistaken the fact that the folders have white spaces in them shouldn't affect the process since it uses the flag `-f`.

Comment: You may need `find ... -depth ...`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What is passed to `xargs` is the full path of the file, not just the file name. So your `s/ //` substitute command also removes spaces from the directory part. And as the new directories (without spaces) don't exist you get the error you see. The renaming, in your example, was:

```
./FOLDER WITH SPACES/FOLDER1.1/SUBFOLDER1.1/FILE.01 A.jpg ->
./FOLDERWITH SPACES/FOLDER1.1/SUBFOLDER1.1/FILE.01 A.jpg
```

And this is not possible if directories `./FOLDERWITH SPACES/FOLDER1.1/SUBFOLDER1.1` don't already exist.

Try with the `-d` option of `rename`:

```sh
find . -type f -name '* *' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -d 's/ //'
```

(the `-d` option only renames the filename component of the path.)

Note that you don't need `xargs`. You could use the `-execdir` action of `find`:

```
find . -type f -name '* *' -execdir rename 's/ //' {} +
```

And as the `-execdir` command is executed in the subdirectory containing the matched file, you don't need the `-d` option of `rename` any more. And the `-print0` action of `find` is not needed neither.

Last note: if you want to replace **all** spaces in the file names, not just the first one, do not forget to add the `g` flag: `rename 's/ //g'`.

Answer (score 1):

You're correct in that `-type f -name '* *'` only finds files with blanks in the name, but `find` prints the entire path including parent directories, so if you have

```
dir with blank/file with blank.txt
```

and you do `rename 's/ //'` on that string, you get

```
dirwith blank/file with blank.txt
```

because the first blank in the entire string was removed. And now the path has changed, invalidating previously found results.

You could

- use a different incantation of `rename` to a) only apply to the part after the last `/` and b) replace multiple blanks:

  ```sh
  find . -type f -name '* *' -print0 | xargs -0 rename -n 's| (?=[^/]*$)||g'
  ```

  `s/ (?=[^\/]*$)//g` matches all blanks that are followed by characters other than `/` until the end of the string, where `(?=...)` is a [look-ahead](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlre#(?=pattern)).<sup>1</sup> You can use `rename -n` to dry-run until everything looks right.
- (with GNU `find`) use `-execdir` to operate relative to the directory where the file is found, and also use Bash parameter expansion instead of `rename`:

  ```sh
  find \
      -type f \
      -name '* *' \
      -execdir bash -c 'for f; do mv "$f" "${f//[[:blank:]]}"; done' _ {} +
  ```

  This collects as many matches as possible and then calls the Bash command with all the matches; `for f` iterates over all positional parameters (i.e., each file), and the `mv` command removes all blanks. `_` is a stand-in for `$0` within `bash -c` and doesn't really do anything.

  `${f//[[:blank:]]}` is a [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) that removes all instances of `[[:blank:]]` from the string `$f`.

  You can use `echo mv` until everything looks right.

---

<sup>1</sup> There's an easier method to achieve the same using `rename -d`, see [Renaud's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69737363/3266847).